# Тире перед наречием?

Tags: пунктуация

Брать у туристов рискованно. Тире не нужно перед рискованно?

Answer (score 3):

(1) **Брать у туристов рискованно.**  Нет тире, именная часть сказуемого выражена наречием.

(2) **Брать у туристов ― рискованно.** Авторское тире при противопоставлении и логическом выделении первой части.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что здесь в любом случае нужно тире, поскольку пропущен необходимый член предложения: прямое дополнение (существительное или местоимение) после переходного глагола "брать" (если только речь идёт не о *взятке*, что маловероятно). Тире выполняет здесь функцию замещения пропущенного элемента, о котором, вероятно, говорилось ранее, например:

> (Нужно обязательно найти это лекарство в аптеке.)
>
> Брать у туристов [подобные препараты] - рискованно.